# How to fit Word2Vec on test data?

Tags: python, word2vec, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I am working on a **Sentiment Analysis** problem. I am using Gensim's Word2Vec to vectorize my data in the following way:

```
# PREPROCESSING THE DATA

# SPLITTING THE DATA
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_x,test_x,train_y,test_y = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 69, stratify = y)

train_x2 = train_x['review'].to_list()
test_x2 = test_x['review'].to_list()

# CONVERT TRIAN DATA INTO NESTED LIST AS WORD2VEC EXPECTS A LIST OF LIST TOKENS
train_x3 = [nltk.word_tokenize(k) for k in train_x2]
test_x3 = [nltk.word_tokenize(k) for k in test_x2]

# TRAIN THE MODEL ON TRAIN SET
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec(train_x3, min_count = 1)
key_index = model.wv.key_to_index

# MAKE A DICT
we_dict = {word:model.wv[word] for word in key_index}

# CONVERT TO DATAFRAME
import pandas as pd
new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(we_dict)
```

The new dataframe is the vectorized form of the train data. Now how do I do the same process for the test data? I can't pass the whole corpus (train+test) to the Word2Vec instance as it might lead to data leakage. Should I simply pass the test list to another instance of the model as:

```
model = Word2Vec(test_x3, min_count = 1)
```

I dont think so this would be the correct way. Any help is appreciated!

**PS:** I am not using the pretrained word2vec in an LSTM model. What I am doing is training the Word2Vec on the data that I have and then feeding it to a ML algorithm like RF or LGBM. Hence I need to vectorize the test data separately.

Answer (score 1):

Note that because word2vec is an *unsupervised* algorithm, it can sometimes be defensible to use *all* available texts to train it. That includes texts with known labels that you're witthiolding from other supervised-classification steps as test/validation records.

You just make sure the labels themselves aren't in the training data, but still use the bulk unlabeled text for further unsupervised improvement of the raw word-vectors. Those vectors, influenced by *all* the input text (but none of the known-answer labels) are then used for enhanced feature-modeling of the texts, as input to later supervised label-aware steps.

(Whether this is Ok for your project may depend on what future performance you want your various accuracy/etc evaluation measures to be reasonably estimate. Is it new situations where everything always must be trained from scratch, and where relevant raw text and labels as training data are both scarce? Or situations where the corpus always grows, & text is always plentiful even if labels are expensive to acquite, or where any actual deployed classifiers will be able to leverage other unlabeled texts before committing to a prediction?)

But note also: word-vectors are only comparison-compatible with each other when trained together, into a shared space. (Or, made compatible via other less-common post-training alginment steps.) There's no single right place for any word's vector, just a good relative position, with regard to everything trained in the same session – which used randomization in both initialization, & training, so even repeated runs on the same training data can yield end models of approximately-equivalent usefulness with wildly-different word-coordinates.

So, when withholding your test-set texts from initial word2vec training, you might alternatives *never* train a separate word2vec model on just the test texts, but rather use the frozen word2vec model from training data.

Separately: `min_count=1` is almost always a bad idea for word2vec models, & if you're tempted to do so, you may have far too little data for such a data-hungry algorithm to show its true value. (If using it on the datasets where it really shines, you should be more often *raising* that threshold above its default – discarding more rare words – than lowering it to save every rare, hard-to-model-well word.)

Comment: `but rather use the frozen word2vec model from training data.` So what you mean is us the same model that was used on training data, to train the test data? How can I do that?

Comment: @spectre after training, word2vec gives you a vector for every word seen in the training data (although you should remove low frequency words, as mentioned by gojomo). These vectors are now your pretrained vectors, so with the test data you map every word to its corresponding vector. Rare words which were not in the training data (or not frequent enough) can simply be ignored.

Comment: @Erwan https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49431/how-to-train-an-existing-word2vec-gensim-model-on-new-words Instead of mapping can I train that same model on the test set as shown in this link?

Comment: In the link the answer says to simply train the model on the new data. Similarly I can train the model that was trained on train set on the test set. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @spectre If what you mean is (like in the linked question) to "update the model" in order to obtain new embeddings for the unknown words in the test set, it's possible but: (1) if you're going to train embeddings also for the test set, it's more efficient to directly train word2vec on both the training and test set. Methodology-wise It's not very clean to use the test set, but as gojomo said it's ok-ish given that word2vec is unsupervised. (2) there's a high risk that there's not enough data in the test set to train good embeddings. In particular in "production mode" it should be possible ...

Comment: ... to have even only one instance as test set, so the idea of using only the test set to train embeddings is not really generalizable, it could lead to problems when using the model later. Note that I'm not an expert in this so don't take my word for it.

Comment: @Erwan `it's more efficient to directly train word2vec on both the training and test set.`  1.) Won't that lead to data leakage? 2.) In your previous comment you said `so with the test data you map every word to its corresponding vector.`. How can I do that and won't it be cumbersome to map each and every word in the test set to the train? Also not all words that are in the train set will be present in the test set.

Comment: @spectre 1) yes absolutely, there is a risk of data leakage. the risk is small because the way word2vec works is unlikely to influence the training, but in principle it should be avoided. However in my opinion the idea of retraining word2vec with the test data later is not much better in principle because of my point (2) above, so none of the two options is perfect.

Comment: 2) word2vec takes as input a large corpus and produces as output a vector (word embedding) for every word in the corpus (or a subset of the words). The output can be seen as a dictionary: every word is associated with a vector. The point is to later use the numerical vector to represent the word instead of a one-hot encoded representation (for instance). So even for the training of the target task (for instance classification), one needs to replace every word with its corresponding vector. The standard way to proceed on the test set is to just ignore words for which there is no vector, but

Comment: ... as we said there are alternatives. In general the out of vocabulary words don't matter much, so I'm not sure it's worth the trouble and the possible disadvantages.